# Problem with my walking in gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

Hello I am making a game with my friend and I am the scripter and I wanted to sort out walking he is coming to help me tomorrow. So when I click to go left I go right here is my code [image: My code to go left.]

Here is my code to go right[image: My code to go right.]

Comment: How does the behaviour of this code differ from what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I believe that you want to change the `X Coordinate`, by `move_speed` to go right, and by `-move_speed` to go left.
- I'm not sure about the sprite. Since I see it says "left" on the name.
- I would expect that if you wanted to flip the sprite the horizontal scaling would be `-1` (and `1` for not flipping it). Not `-2`.

Comment: hey, my walking is fixed thank you! But my character gets really small for some reason can you help me again thanks!

Comment: @LDLwarrior2 it "gets" small? I can only guess it has to do with the instance scale. Did you scale it up when you placed it? The default scaling is `1` for both horizontal and vertical, perhaps you want a different value. For example `2` for double the size, and then `-2` to flip it.

Comment: no it is still small :/